# Nth word in a string variable

Tags: bash

In Bash, I want to get the Nth word of a string hold by a variable.

For instance:

```
STRING="one two three four"
N=3
```

Result:

```
"three"
```

What Bash command/script could do this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
echo $STRING | cut -d " " -f $N
```

Comment: cut will fail when requesting a field which does not exist.  Instead of returning "" it will return the string itself.  Example:  echo"aaaa" | cut -f2 result is "aaaa", not blank zero length result.

Comment: @ajaaskel That seems to happen when the _delimiter_ is not found in the input. And that behavior can nowadays be altered by using option --only-delimited.

Comment: cut will also fail if the string has a leading space, because of destructive transformations by sed for example.

Answer (score 70):

An alternative

```
N=3
STRING="one two three four"

arr=($STRING)
echo ${arr[N-1]}
```

Comment: Using bash arrays for this is "the best" solution, I hate to use awk or sed, as I don't see them installed on all setups especially the msys setup.

Comment: Even though the echo "isn't necessary", I found it useful for understanding how to use the arr elements. Thanks

Comment: If you have set `IFS` (the internal field separator) to ':' or something instead of white space, change it back before trying this.

Comment: This should be the right answer.  Using arrays for this purpose is both simple and clever.

Comment: Note that it will fail if a "word" is "*" ([asterisk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asterisk#Noun)) - it will bring in a list of all files and all directories in the current directory.

Answer (score 35):

Using `awk`

```
echo $STRING | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}'
```

Test

```
% N=3
% STRING="one two three four"
% echo $STRING | awk -v N=$N '{print $N}'
three
```

Answer (score 13):

A file containing some statements:

```
cat test.txt
```

Result:

```
This is the 1st Statement
This is the 2nd Statement
This is the 3rd Statement
This is the 4th Statement
This is the 5th Statement
```

So, to print the 4th word of this statement type:

```
awk '{print $4}' test.txt
```

Output:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
```

Comment: The OP says that the string is in a variable, not a file.

Answer (score 4):

No expensive forks, no pipes, no bashisms:

```
$ set -- $STRING
$ eval echo \${$N}
three
```

Or, if you want to avoid `eval`,

```
$ set -- $STRING
$ shift $((N-1))
$ echo $1
three
```

But beware of globbing (use `set -f` to turn off filename globbing).

Comment: Does it handle one of the "words" being "*" [asterisk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asterisk#Noun)? [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005627/nth-word-in-a-string-variable#comment118884916_3005687) doesn't.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It can do both. After `set -f` if will not glob-expand an asterisk, with `set +f` (the default) it will.

Answer (score 2):

```
STRING=(one two three four)
echo "${STRING[n]}"
```

Comment: In you example, is STRING really a string? It looks like an array.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes actually you're right. But I have written to be an alternative to.