# Cut is working unexpected?

Tags: bash, cut

I want to cut a line into fields with custom delimeter:

```
echo "field1   field2    field3" | cut -d\  -f2
```

I expect `field2` to show in result, but I get nothing. How can I split it with `cut`?

Comment: Is a delimiter a tab?

Comment: Dup?  See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one/24543432#24543432

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that there's more than one space. `cut(1)` doesn't collapse the delimiter. It will split on the first delimiter encountered.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) has this to say about it (emphasis mine):

> - **-f**  *list*
>     Cut based on a list of fields, assumed to be separated in the file by a delimiter character (see -d). Each selected field shall be output. **Output fields shall be separated by a single occurrence of the field delimiter character.** Lines with no field delimiters shall be passed through intact, unless -s is specified. It shall not be an error to select fields not present in the input line.

Solutions:

1. If you're on FreeBSD, use `-w`; this will split on whitespace (while very useful, this is non-standard; and *not* portable to GNU cut)
2. Use `-f 4`
3. use `awk(1)`: `echo "field1   field2    field3" | awk '{print $2}'`
4. Use `tr(1)` to collapse all spaces to a single space: `echo "field1   field2    field3" | tr -s \  | cut -d\  -f2`

Comment: I'm aware of `awk` (as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005627/bash-nth-word-in-a-string), but I'm frustrated that top answer there doesn't work.

Comment: @danbst This actually makes sense :-) I've updated my answer with some extra explanation on what's going on

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
echo "field1   field2    field3" | awk '{print $2}'
field2
```

since `cut` doesn't handle multiple delimiters correctly.

Or else use `tr` to truncate multiple spaces into one first:

```
echo "field1   field2    field3" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
field2
```